# How to get the first row from a table based on multiple group by

Tags: postgresql, duplicates

I have a PostgreSQL table and need to select the first record based on different groups of columns (each time group by a combination of different columns).

`table1 (id1, id2, id3, id4, u1, u2, u3, ...)`

I tried this code and it works fine.

```
select 
  t.*,
  row_number() over (partition by id1, id2) as rn1,
  row_number() over (partition by id1, id3) as rn2,
  row_number() over (partition by id1, id2, id4) as rn3
from table1 t
```

and I need only the first records from each group (rn1 = 1, rn2 = 1, rn3 = 1).

```
case when rn1 = 1 and u1 > 0 then 1 else 0 as res1
case when rn2 = 1 and u2 = 1 then 1 else 0 as res2
case when rn3 = 1 and u3 < 0 then 1 else 0 as res3
```

But this query is very slow and need to rewrite it without using any window function. Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: Please include the full query which has those `CASE` expressions in it.  Also, sample input/output would help here.

Comment: If I correctly understood your question using limit 1 after the from table statement should work for you .    https://www.petefreitag.com/item/59.cfm

Comment: limit 1 with row_number? there should not be any window function in the query...